# Python If else / switch

Tags: python, if-statement

I am coding a query for a name, favourite game and what the rank of the user is.

When the user says they're between iron–platinum, I want the message to be something like "u are trash" or so, just for test. And if the user is above platinum → diamond–immortal the output should be something like "sheesh" or "nice".

```
lowelo = ["Iron", "Bronze", "Silver", "Gold", "Plat"]

highelo = ["Diamond", "Ascendand", "Immortal", "Radiant"]

name = input("whats ur name:")

fav_game = input("what is your favourite game?:") # is for valorant ment
rank = input("What is your rank in the game?:")
def rank_output(lowelo):
    if rank == lowelo:
        print("you are trash", name)
    elif rank ==highelo:
        print("good job")
rank_output(rank)
```

I just have python 3.9 currently and can't do a `match`, so I went for an `if` statement. I just need the code fixed so I can understand it.

Comment: simply number your values, like iron = 0 and bronze = 1, so if the user enters 0.4 then display trash

Comment: @trincot `match` was introduced in Python 3.10. There is no `switch`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key fix for your issue is that you want to use `in` to test if an item is found in a list, not `==` which you would use to test if two strings or two lists were equal to each other. Here is how you might do that. Note that this code corrects a slight confusion that might result from passing a variable called `rank` into a method that has a parameter called `lowelo`

```py
lowelo = ["Iron", "Bronze", "Silver", "Gold", "Plat"]
highelo = ["Diamond", "Ascendand", "Immortal", "Radiant"]

name = input("whats ur name:")
fav_game = input("what is your favourite game?:") # is for valorant ment
rank = input("What is your rank in the game?:")

def rank_output(rank):  # <---- renamed parameter
    if rank in lowelo:
        print("you are trash", name)
    elif rank in highelo:
        print("good job")

rank_output(rank)
```

Comment: The argument should be `rank` not `lowelo`, but that is the OP's typo, otherwise this is precisely what they're seeking.

Comment: yes, i just checked the error in logic, missed to see OP passed lowle instead of rank

Answer (score 0):

```
highelo = ["Diamond", "Ascendand", "Immortal", "Radiant"]

name = input("whats ur name:")

fav_game = input("what is your favourite game?:") # is for valorant ment
rank = input("What is your rank in the game?:")
def rank_output(rank, lowelo, highlo):
    if rank in lowelo:
        print("you are trash", name)
    elif rank in highelo:
        print("good job")
    else:
        print("Entered 'rank' is not recognized")
rank_output(rank, lowelo, highlo)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is the working Code:

```
lowelo = ["Iron", "Bronze", "Silver", "Gold", "Plat"]

highelo = ["Diamond", "Ascendand", "Immortal", "Radiant"]

name = input("whats ur name:")

fav_game = input("what is your favourite game?:")  # is for valorant ment
rank = input("What is your rank in the game?:")


def rank_output(player_rank):
    if player_rank in lowelo:
        print("you are trash", name)
    elif player_rank in highelo:
        print("good job")


rank_output(rank)
```

There are several problems with your code:

1. You want to check if a variable is in a list, for this you dont use "==", but 'in' => `if rank in lowelo:`
2. The problem is, that the function gets a variable named "lowelo" `def rank_output(lowelo):`, but your list is already named `lowelo = ["Iron", "Bronze", "Silver", "Gold", "Plat"]`, so it will override this list with the rank the user put in, so you need to change the name of the parameter variable, I changed it to "player_rank"